# pyCharm with red squiggly lines under every import statement that references another file

Tags: python, import, pycharm

For some reason, pycharm gives me red squiggly lines under every import statement in every file that is importing another file. For example in one file I have:

```
from globals import *
```

In which the word "globals" has a red squiggly, and in every function from globals.py that I have, it cannot find the definition to. The file globals.py is in the same directory as the file that is referencing it. This happens with every file I have. Has anyone gotten this? For some reason this only started happening after I made my default python Python 3.6 (instead of 2.7). Thanks in advance!

I also realize that I can fix the red squiggly issue by instead writing:

```
from .globals import *
```

however, when I try to the run the script in debug mode I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.globals'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Comment: Try renaming your `globals.py` to something else and import that name instead. `globals` is the name of a built-in function so I suspect that the interpreter might get confused.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a module as a script, correct?  The file where `from globals import *` is located is itself inside a proper package?